# How to know which CSS3 properties require vendor prefixes like -webkit-,-moz-,-0- etc.?

Tags: css, wordpress

I use wordpress and every now and then have to add custom CSS with some 'lesser' known properties like `isolation` and just add it like `isolation: isolate;`. But what I would like to know is that do I really need to go to **caniuse(dot)com** and check the '**Notes**' tab for each property  every time I have to add some custom CSS to learn about its vendor prefix requirement? Is this the only way? Any comprehensive cheatsheet-'type' content exists? I'm not sure because I have seem some 'seemingly' common CSS properties too utilizing those prefixes. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: *Any comprehensive cheatsheet-'type' content exists?* --> you already found it: caniuse

Comment: @TemaniAfif I guess that is all there is. I thought maybe an experienced dev has some other trick to share.

Comment: If you don't know then experienced/professional uses the **Autoprefix** postCSS plugin with their package builder(gulp, grunt, webpack, etc) by specifying the **browerlist**, if you don't use any package builder then you can use this website https://autoprefixer.github.io/ and generate vendor prefixs for your CSS code.